# How to install WFDB Toolbox for MATLAB on Code Ocean?

Tags: matlab, toolbox

I am trying to run the wfdbdemo in Code Ocean.

In the postInstall script on Code Ocean, by following the [instructions](https://help.codeocean.com/en/articles/1110985-installing-user-provided-matlab-toolboxes), I have tried to install WFDB toolbox for MATLAB and [Octave](https://archive.physionet.org/physiotools/matlab/wfdb-app-matlab/) on Code Ocean without success.

Does anyone have an idea how to do it?

Comment: `.....on Code Ocean without success.` What error are you facing? Can you post the same?

Comment: Embedded link to batter readability.

Answer (score 1):

I have finally arrived to install the toolbox on Code Ocean.

In the environment section, you can create a postInstall file with the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash 
set -e

curl -s https://physionet.org/physiotools/matlab/wfdb-app-matlab/wfdb-app-toolbox-0-10-0.zip --output wfdb-app-toolbox-0-10-0.zip
unzip -qq wfdb-app-toolbox-0-10-0.zip
echo 'wfdb-app-toolbox-0-10-0.zip'

matlab -nodisplay -r "\
cd /mcode;\
addpath(pwd);\
savepath;"
```

Please refer to https://codeocean.com/capsule/5659038/tree/v1 to check the capsule I have created to install the WFDB Toolbox for MATLAB and Octave on Code Ocean.